# How can i type a Vue component created using Vue.extend?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

Using Vue with TypeScript, I have created two components using **Vue.extend**. I now want to access one of them via **this.$refs** from the other, but i can't access any of its methods via IDE autocomplete if i don't specify its type:

```
// ChildComponent.vue

export default Vue.extend({
  name: 'ChildComponent',
  methods: {
    test(): void { ... }
  }
}

// ParentComponent.vue

<template>
  <ChildComponent ref="child_ref" />
</template>

export default Vue.extend({
  name: 'ParentComponent',
  components: { ChildComponent }
  computed: {
    child(): InstanceType<typeof ChildComponent> { // This won't work 
      return this.$refs.child_ref as InstanceType<typeof ChildComponent>;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    triggerChildTest(): void {  
      this.child.test(); // IDE warning: Property 'test' does not exist on type 'CombinedVueInstance'.
    }
  }
}
```

Is there any way I can continue to use **Vue.extend** in a way that will allow me to access data & methods from my components? Can i somehow implement an interface on the resulting component?
I would prefer to keep my codebase using this method than migrate everything to use Vue component classes.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. I just tried your code in a Vue CLI generated project with TypeScript. Can you link to a reproduction?

Comment: I can run my code fine with no errors, it's the IDE that marks the method call in red to warn that it couldn't find it inside my $ref. Basically, i can't find a way to type the instance returned by `this.$refs.child_ref` so that i will get autocomplete / IDE TypeScript plugin will understand what I'm working with.

Comment: Yeah I can't reproduce the issue in the IDE (VS Code) or in a build. If it's only happening in your IDE, I assume it's a config issue that's local to your environment.

Comment: Yeah, I'm working on JetBrains Rider with TypeScript enabled. I assume it's the TypeScript checks that are triggering the error, because it checks if the variables / methods exist in the variable they're being accessed from. Thanks anyways, appreciate you looking into it!